# GWT plugin update problem - How to delete Eclipse Helios 3.6 - help

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, uninstallation

I tried to delete the Eclipse Helios 3.6 with GWT plugins manually as I usually did with other eclipse IDEs but now I faced a strange problem. 
A warning window opens which says...

"Cannot delete resources file. Access denied"

So it makes unable to proceed the deleting pressing OK :(

So how to delete Eclipse Helios 3.6?

Any useful comments are appreciated

Comment: Are you logged in with admin privileges?

Comment: Another issue might be a process still running that has one of the files locked. Reboot your system and try it again.

Comment: I had rebooted it for many times yet but hopeless :(

Comment: I used eclipse for gwt only so I don't get it the problem is really come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html) can help see what program has a particular file locked, like joeslice's link, and it can also force that program to relinquish the file handle (which of course could cause bad things to happen in said program so make sure you know what you're doing).

Comment: Well, I am not pretty sure but there, as  I may think, shouldn't be anything else which uses my eclipse plugin folder besides I closed eclipse just before... Do you have any idea what else can use eclipse plugins except eclipse itself? Because I haven't got just a clue :(

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea. But if there is something holding onto it, Unlocker should be able to tell you. Maybe a virus scanner or indexer -- something that's constantly going through all the files on your hard drive...

Comment: I have anti virus software installed. Maybe this one makes the problem?

Comment: The Unlocker showed the explorer.exe is keeping the process but I really don't know why. I deleted the recource files right with Unlocker and it worked :) But why explorer.exe is keeping the eclipse demos folder?

Comment: Is there something else what I should know about Eclipse IDE? I was installing just GWT plugin for it. Just the Eclipse Helios 3.6, as it is, and the newest GWT plugin :( What could keep the process then?

Comment: What if I must delete something more that just Eclipse itself? That's I am worring about :(

Comment: You know the folder I couldn't delete was containing GAE icon images and css files :( What can it be then? Should I delete something else and where I should look it for? I am asking because I had to delete eclipse after update critical error so next I need to reinstall it. And I need to have all configurations clean... How can I find it out?

Answer (score 1):

try to start your computer in safe mode:
when you turn on your computer, push F8(5 times to be sure that it'll work) and after choose safe mode.
You'll be able to delete your files

Comment: But what may keep Eclipse be undeletable? What process? Is it wierd a process is running after I closed the IDE?

Comment: @user592704 Windows is notorious for not releasing file locks properly. It's odd that they are still locked after a reboot though.

Comment: it is the plugin directory... I cannot delete it though I deleted eclipse.exe :( What outer thing may use eclipse plugins?

Answer (score 1):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can help see what's got a particular file locked.

Comment: Oh, Thank you. It is much handy :) Is it free?

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my problem and my final solution...

The problem was because the Eclipse Helios 3.6 internal GWT plugin update error (so the UI Designer doesn't work).
I was trying to update gwt plugins and that made gwt never compile...

So I had to delete it and reinstall.
The reinstallation was OK but since then I tried to download gwt plugin for many times and had the same UI editor error... I think there is a bug in included gwt plugin GWT UI core and window builder.

If someone faces the same problem please read next...

To install GWT for Eclipse Helios 3.6 you should

A) Install GWT UI Designer first from http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.6

B) Only then Install GWT SDK and gwt plugin (to skip the bugged plugin part to be installed)

otherwise if you start from this link http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6, it will install a bugged GWT window builder and core (the newest one) and won't allow you to install the correct one because "the newest is already installed" so you'll have to delete and reinstall etc... That's  a real headache %) So to avoid that follow point A then B.

I hope that will save ones day :)

Good luck